# Adding Areas together unreliable?

Tags: java, collision-detection, area

I am making a 2D game, and loading obstacles from a file as well as the graphics.

Using this code it loads each chunk from a file. When I load the file, I take all the new area objects and add them together so I don't have to loop through them later. Sometimes this works and sometimes it doesn't I don't know why.

As you can see in these two pictures, the black is the obstacles.
It would be fine if it just missed like one or two like in this picture. But sometimes it missed enough for the player to be able to walk though.
I'm certain that it is the areas adding together that's being skipped, because if it was loading from the file incorrectly some of the textures would be missing occasionally, but they never are.

[image]
[image]

```
public static void loadMap() {

    areas.clear();
    areas.put(0, new Area(new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0)));

    InputStream in = RunGame.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
            "chunks/" + chunkX + " " + chunkY + " " + chunkZ);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

    try {
        int i = 0;
        String nextLine = reader.readLine();
        while (nextLine != null) {

            // System.out.println(nextLine);

            String[] split = nextLine.split(", ");
            int[] split2 = new int[split.length];
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < split.length; i1++) {
                split2[i1] = Integer.parseInt(split[i1]);
                if(tiles.get(split2[i1]).isWalkable() == false){
                    areas.get(0).add(tiles.get(split2[i1]).getNewArea((int) mapX + i1 * textureSize,
                                    (int) mapY + i * textureSize));
                }
            }
            mapArray[i] = split2;
            i++;
            nextLine = reader.readLine();
        }
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        currentMapW = mapArray[0].length;
        currentMapH = i;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I am completely open to making the loadMap() method slower if it will be more accurate, worst case scenario I have to add like a tranisition period of like half a second or something.

Comment: When you're modifiying `areas`, i.e. `areas.clear()`, is it possible that it could be being changed within another thread? What happens if you `synchronize` access to `areas`?

Secondly, are the gaps always in the same location? It could be a chunk file error. I really love your graphics, by the way.

Comment: Maybe loading is fine, but the collision detection is not? E.g. can a player move 10 pixels up, from one green area to another green area, over a black line? Collision detection should draw actual lines of motion and see if they cross something, and not rely on the target cell being empty.

Comment: The collision boxes disappear in different place each time, so it's not a chunk error. 

It's pretty much random. And no, the boxes would appear in the drawing in the pictures I posted if the collision box was actually there. It collides with the ones that are there.

Comment: I also don't ever call areas.clear() other than in this part.